# Are immutable integers also collected by the Garbage Collector, like immutable strings?

Tags: c#, immutability, garbage-collection

I already got the idea that string variables are immutable, so the they are copied to another place in heap every time we make a change, and since GarbageCollector has to collect them all the time, it causes performance issues..

Question is:

- Integers or doubles are immutable too. Are they also copied any time we make a change?
- If so, are all copies are collected by garbage collector too?
- Nobody complains about performance about keep changing integers, ever. Is that because there is no point because their allocated memory has to be always the same (8 bit, 16 bit etc), unlike strings?

Comment: Integers are value types, which "saved" in the stack memory. When variable of value types goes out of scope it will be removed from the stack. No need for garbage collector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst both strings and integers are immutable, they aren't the same. Strings are immutable reference types; integers are immutable value types.

If you have a string variable, `s`, then it simply holds a reference (a pointer) to the location in the heap where that string object is stored. If you change the string that `s` refers to, then potentially a new string object is created on the heap and the original one is then eligible for garbage collection if no other references to it remain.

If you however have an `int` variable, `i`, then it holds the integer value. If you change the number held by `i`, then that value changes. There is no *new* heap allocation.

It certainly isn't the case that if you change strings, "the GarbageCollector has to collect them all the time". The garbage collector only runs when it needs to; it's quite possible that during the life of your app, it'll never run. And even when it does run, it can be very fast and not cause performance problems. I'm not saying it never has performance problems; but I am saying that changing strings all the time does not guarantee performance problems.

**Edit**

Regarding `StringBuilder`, this is a memory copying issue; not a garbage collection one. By way of example, consider the following code:

```
var strings = GetListOf1000StringsEach100CharactersLong();
var finalString = "";
foreach (var item in strings)
{
    finalString += item;
}
```

What happens when you run that is:

- First time around, the 100 characters in strings[0] is copied to a new location, referenced by `finalString`.
- Second time through the loop, those 100 characters in `finalString`, plus the 100 in `strings[1]` are copied to a new location and `finalString` updated to point at that location.
- Third time, those 200 characters in `finalString`, plus the 100 in `strings[2]` are copied to a new location and `finalString` updated to point at that location...
- On the last pass, those 99900 characters in `finalString`, plus the 100 in `strings[999]` are copied to a new location and `finalString` updated to point at that location!

As it loops through, the number of characters that has to be copied grows, and those same characters are copied over and over. This is a huge performance problem. `StringBuilder` solves it by just storing references to the original strings and only doing that copy once, when `ToString()` is called. This gives a big performance boost. But it is unrelated to garbage collection.

Comment: That filled out the gap in my mind, thanks. I didnt know GC might never run though. Then why are people are so obsessive about using StringBuilder instead of String?

Comment: @NecatiHakanErdogan David is saying "the GC might never run" in the case of a short lived program. For example a command line utility that starts up does its job and then shuts down. It may never produce enough garbage for running the GC to make sense because the GC isn't looking to ensure no garbage, its looking to ensure you have enough memory left to do you work. Even for long lived programs it won't run "all the time" but "every few seconds" or "every few minutes" or  "every few hours" depending on how much garbage your program produces

Comment: @RichardTingle thanks, I got it. This "Never ever use string instead of StrngBuilder" obsession might be something carried out from the old times we don't have enough memory for it.

Comment: @NecatiHakanErdogan, I have updated my answer to explain why `StringBuilder` improves performance.

Comment: @NecatiHakanErdogan If you're wondering why you should use StringBuilder, you probably haven't met [Shlemiel the Painter](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/)?

Comment: Thanks @Doval, I am aware the issue as I stated the original post. I was just curious to know what is the difference between integer on this.

Comment: @Doval, I'd forgotten about Shlemiel. I love that analogy to the problem `StringBuilder` solves. I'm sure there's a proper term (exponential, or N(something) or some such) that describes it too, but I'm not too hot on formal terms.

Comment: @Necati the reason I bring it up is that memory isn't the only cost when you're not using a StringBuilder in a loop - you're also wasting CPU copying the same characters over and over into new strings. This isn't a problem for fixed size numbers because addition/multiplication/etc take roughly the same amount of time regardless of what the value of the numbers are.

Comment: Using `StringBuilder` is very much related to garbage collection. All those "new locations" you talk about are heap allocated, which means they increase GC pressure and cause the GC to run more often. Also, `StringBuilder` does not store references, as far as I can tell from its code, it always copies the string when you call `Append()`.

Comment: @svick, You have completely misunderstood the question and my answer. Of course using `StringBuilder` involves the heap and thus *could* involve the GC. That's orthogonal though. The issue is that if `StringBuilder` isn't used then a large string creation task will involve lots of memory allocation and lots of copying, which can be a huge performance hit.

Comment: @DavidArno It's you who misunderstood, sorry if I was unclear. I'm not saying that using `StringBuilder` causes GC issues. I'm saying that *not using* `StringBuilder` creates lots of garbage, which can cause GC issues. It also involves lots of copying, but that means there are two performance issues with it (copying and GC), but you ignore one of them.

Comment: @svick, Ah yes, I misunderstand you. Sure I  did ignore the GC issues with copying lots of strings and ignored the real internals of `Append` (with it's unsafe byte copying) as I wanted to keep things simple.